How is the logging module still outputting even when stdout and stderr are set to None?
This is a simple proof-of-concept script
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info('This is a test for info')
logging.error('This is a test for error')
print('This is a test for print')

sys.__stdout__ = None
sys.stdout = None

sys.__stderr__ = None
sys.stderr = None

logging.info('This is a test for info after setting stdout to None')
logging.error('This is a test for error after setting stderr to None')
print('This is a test for print after setting stdout to None')

And the output is:
INFO:root:This is a test for info
ERROR:root:This is a test for error
This is a test for print
INFO:root:This is a test for info after setting stdout to None
ERROR:root:This is a test for error after setting stderr to None

As you can see the print statement is not outputting the string after setting stdout/stderr to None.
But how is the logging module still outputting the strings into the terminal, is there a reason behind this?

The handers created by logging.basicConfig holder their own references to the process's standard error; they don't use the expressions sys.stderr or sys.__stderr__.

@chepner this is why of what observed in answer below ?? Where is it described in docs, tried to went through it but didnt find any reference (too long docs , to difficult to me , not able to understand a lot of it)

When you call basicConfig with the arguments shown, a new instance of StreamHandler is created using None as the argument; in that case, the current value of sys.stderr is assigned to the handler's stream attribute.

I don't know; nevertheless try adding:
logging.basicConfig(stream=None , force=True)

after: sys.stderr = None
Then try again with:
logging.basicConfig(stream=None)

Then try the output of:
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info('This is a test for info')
logging.error('This is a test for error')
print('This is a test for print')

sys.__stdout__ = None
sys.stdout = None

sys.__stderr__ = None
sys.stderr = None

logging.basicConfig(stream = sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG , force= True)

logging.info('This is a test for info after setting stdout to None')
logging.error('This is a test for error after setting stderr to None')
print('This is a test for print after setting stdout to None')

And again try to change:
logging.basicConfig(stream = sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG , force= True)

to:
logging.basicConfig(stream = sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG , force= False)

